How to set Edges in Gephi - soil ecology
I am totally new on gephi. I have a list of soil bacteria in different experimental sites. I would like to understand if they form specific assemblages (community).
My raw file consists in a list of Bacteria (species) and the relative abundance (%).
Once I get into gephi the software ask me for edges. How do I get this edges since I have no idea on how they relate to each other? Should I calculate for instance a correlation?
Thank you very much for any input you can provide
I would need to divide the species into communities

Welcome to StackOverflow. The term edges in networks, represents some kind of interaction/relationship between the entities denoted as nodes. An example of such an interaction could be a bibliographic citation, between articles. In your csae, it is not very obvious if the nature of your problem, allows such interactions. A correlation, can show such relationships, if I am not wrong, provided that the correlation does have a meaning in your research.

@YannisP. Thank you for your reply. Correlation has a meaning in my research. Nevertheless, GEPHI does not support negative correlations. Should I just remove them? What is your take on that? thank you!

I think you better represent the bacteria you are correlaring as nodes and their correlations become edges. Gephi does not represent correlation as such, because correlation is not something in the definition of networks, I would call it a metric that shows how the nodes are connected, correlated in your case.
Edges have however weights, which can represent the correlation force, even a negative one
